# If condition for alert box

Tags: javascript

I want to create function for if alert box clicked okay it will execute the **show_popup()**. It is not working. 
**My code is below:**

```
function show_popup(){

document.getElementById('hover_bkgr_fricc').style.display = 'block';
}
function hide_popup(){
document.getElementById('hover_bkgr_fricc').style.display = 'none';
}

window.onblur = function() {

if(alert("click ok")){
show_popup();
}

};
```

Comment: Hey - did an answer help you? Is this still a relevant problem? I see you have not accepted any answer.

Comment: i used confirm instead of alert

Comment: So maybe accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `confirm` instead, try this:

```
var result = confirm("Want to delete?");

if (result) {
 // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried that. Confirm box is not appearing onblur event if we navigate other tab within same browser.

Comment: you sure event window.onblur worked. let's check by console.log().I think that is problem , sorry about my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Alert boxes don't function like that, they simply show an alert and continue forwards after the alert is cleared.

Think about it like this, how would the user affect / choose to go inside the if or inside the else here?

You might be looking for `window.confirm` instead of `window.alert`.

For better info, see

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Answer (score 0):

This is not how alert works,

The alert function halts the execution of the code until it's dismissed. This means that any code you want to run after the alert has been clicked can simply be placed after the call to the alert method.

put your function just after the alert line in your code...

```
alert("whatever you want");
show_popup();
```